# Session Error on createView - Symfony 5.0

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 5.0.11 trying to render a form. For some reason on the `$form->createView()` call it throws the error 'Failed to start the session: already started by PHP.' It is only happening on this form, my other forms are working fine. Other routes in this class are working as well. Here's my code...
Controller method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Site;
use App\Form\SiteType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class SitesController extends AbstractController
{

     /**
     * @Route("/sites/add", name="app_sites_add")
     */
    public function site_add(EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(SiteType::class);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $site = $form->getData();

            $em->persist($site);
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Site Successfully Added!');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('sites');
        } else {
            return $this->render('sites/form.html.twig', ['siteForm' => $form->createView()]);
        }

    }
}
```

Form Method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Site;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SiteType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('url')
            ->add('type')
            ->add('is_active')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Site::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here's the trace:

````
  /app/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php:148 
  /app/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Session.php:57 
  /app/vendor/symfony/security-csrf/TokenStorage/SessionTokenStorage.php:77 
  /app/vendor/symfony/security-csrf/CsrfTokenManager.php:72 
  /app/vendor/symfony/form/Extension/Csrf/Type/FormTypeCsrfExtension.php:77 
  /app/vendor/symfony/form/ResolvedFormType.php:168 
  /app/vendor/symfony/form/Extension/DataCollector/Proxy/ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy.php:111 
  /app/vendor/symfony/form/ResolvedFormType.php:161 
  /app/vendor/symfony/form/Extension/DataCollector/Proxy/ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy.php:111 
  /app/vendor/symfony/form/Form.php:1039
  /app/src/Controller/SitesController.php:98 
    App\Controller\SitesController->site_edit(Site $id, EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $request) …
     return $this->render('sites/form.html.twig', [
         'siteForm' => $form->createView()
     ]);
  }
  /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:157 
  /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:79 
  /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:191 
  /app/public/index.php:25 
}```

Thanks for your help.
````

Comment: you most likely have space or empty line before the very top `<?php` of some relevant file which already outputs stuff and thus starts the output buffer, killing any later attempts to set headers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was in the security configuration. I'm using the guard authenticator and I hadn't setup a firewall rule for these forms.

Comment: I have the same problem, can you please share more information? I don't understand what I have to do and on which configuration file.